# How to make result of user input fold directly under one another?

Tags: c, algorithm

I have this function where I am folding the user input whenever it reaches the MAXLINE limit. However, instead of the output moving to the left of a completely new line, it staggers where it left off from the previous line. I've included an image below.

[image: Picture of user input dropping off]

This is not what I want however. I'd like for the user input to reach its limit and fold completely into an actual brand new line (starting at the farthest left). How can I do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>            

#define MAXLINE 10


// count number of chars, once it reaches certain amount
int main (void) 
{
    //cbreak();
    //echo();

    // to open curses terminal
    initscr();

    int i, c;

    for (i = 1; (c = getch()) != ERR; i++)
    {
         if (i == MAXLINE)
         {
             printf("\n");
             //refresh();
             i = 0;          // Counter is reset. To break out of the loop use CTRL + D.
         }
    }

    //printf("%d\n",i);
    // to close curses terminal
    endwin();
}
```

How can I improve this? Thank you.

Comment: And what about `printf("\r\n");`?

Comment: It looks like you're getting the line feed character without the carriage return.  Have you tried it without using ncurses/initscr/endwin?  Normally you wouldn't use `printf` when using ncurses, but would instead use things like `printw`.

Comment: @Mathieu printf("\r\n"); worked for me. Tom Karzes, I will look into using "printw". Thank you.

Comment: The whole point of using ncurses is to allow you to place text anywhere on the screen, as opposed to producing a single sequential stream of characters.  But it looks like you're just using it as a way to access your terminal.  Can't you just run your program directly from your terminal?  I haven't seen any need for using ncurses in the posted code.